# How can I use VBA to load contents into a cell comment?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that I will update monthly that tracks the percentage of applications approved.
I want to be able to hover over a cell and see, in a comment, data relevent to the contents of that cell. For example:

[image]

This is a snip of my Trend tab.

There is 2016Data tab where 123 is the count of applications received in the month of January 2016 and 102 is the count of applications that were approved. The 2016Data tab is static and does not change as it is historic reference to compare this year against last.

There is a 2017Data tab that has the same information but this information will be refreshed monthly.

NOTE: All application records on the data tabs are notated in column A:A with a 1 so I can sum the columns where other attributes exist to help me analyze data. As well each application is notated with a 1 or 0 in column B:B so I can sum that column to know the number of applications approved. Here is a sample of information on those data tabs:
[image]

I manually created the snip above to show what I'm trying to re-create in VBA and each time I refresh 2017Data I need all the counts to be updated in all of the comments automatically.

Also worth noting - I am a VBA toddler, and my experience with it is very limited.

Comment: Try this here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196533.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Below is how you can create a comment to a cell.

```
Dim mySheet, myCell
Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set myCell = mySheet.Cells(1, 1)

On Error Resume Next 'In case there is an existing comment to the cell already, you will get an error
myCell.AddComment
myCell.Comment.Visible = False
myCell.Comment.Text Text:="myComment text"
```

You will have to write to own logic to read the content from your source sheet and add as a comment on your destination.

```
'Read from a cell
Dim strCellVal
strCellVal = myCell.Value

'Write to a cell
myCell.Value = "My Cell Content"
```

**--EDIT--**

Try below to loop each cells,

```
Dim UsedRange, CurrentCell
' Assuming your data starts from cell A1
UsedRange = "$A$1:" + mySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address

For Each CurrentCell In mySheet.Range(UsedRange).Cells
   MsgBox CurrentCell
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! There are 576 cells on the page that I do this to. Will I need to create 576 modules to do this?

Comment: Nope, you can simply loop through each cells. Ideally SO is not a place where you'd get a complete code for your need. But, you will get help when you are stuck. Let me update the answer, with a looping logic try that and post your code. We will help you fix it! :)

Comment: "SO is not a place where you'd get a complete code for your need" One can wish and hope, right?

Comment: Yep! One can! :) I've updated my answer with a looping logic try that and see how it goes !